# Как из Python управлять PowerPoint?

Tags: python, windows-10, subprocess

Задача. Из скрипта на Python управлять работой программы PowerPoint. Как-то передавать туда команды типа - "следующий слайд", "слайд №5", "в начало презентации". Google не помог пока - не знаю как задать вопрос.
Как запустить `subprocess` понятно... а как туда нажатия клавиш передавать?
Я нашел альтернативное решение  -   через модуль [pyWin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918290/python-activate-last-slide-in-active-powerpoint-presentation)... но оно годиться только для винды...  и не подходит для OpenOfice

Подойдет ответ на более общий вопрос:
"**Как передавать нажатие клавиш в субпроцесс**"?

Comment: нет, не понятино..добавте тег Виндовс, Питон и поверпоит есть и на андроиде с iOS.    

Конкретно по нажатиям клавишь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python

Comment: увы - метки powerpoint я не нашел. А как добавлять метки я не знаю.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Interact with other programs using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279)

Comment: в PowerPoint, как и в других MS приложениях, используется скриптовый язык VBA, но можно установить и Python. Гуглите, я встраивал в Excel(название не помню)

Comment: @Arantler: попробуйте нажать на ссылку в вопросе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все же простейшим решением стал этот путь:

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time  

cmd = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\POWERPNT.EXE"'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.press('f5')
```

Надо только следить, чтобы Powerpoint всегда был "сверху" )) куда и передается нажатие `f5`.
О неудовлетворенности от `pywinauto` см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745763/pywinauto-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5/745903#745903).

Comment: Я создал первый ответ (который теперь второй) А потом нашел другой. Попроще как на меня. В следующий раз - объединю. Ок.

Answer (score 3):

Благодарю @[Reishin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/274393/reishin) за [подсказку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791839/which-is-the-easiest-way-to-simulate-keyboard-and-mouse-on-python). 
Вот ответ с клавишами используя модуль `pywinauto` для "notepad.exe".
Надеюсь - найду там и для powerpoint

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start("notepad.exe")
app.notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
app.Notepad.MenuSelect("File->SaveAs")
app.SaveAs.ComboBox5.Select("UTF-8")
app.SaveAs.edit1.SetText("Example-utf8.txt")
app.SaveAs.Save.Click()
```

Кстати! для русскоязычной винды надо писать

```
 app.Notepad.MenuSelect("Файл->СохранитьКак")
```

Кроме этого, благодарю @[jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) за указание на модуль  [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#purpose). Опробую - напишу.

Comment: если вы хотите пойти по пути симуляции движения мыши, нажатия клавиш, то [стоит pyautogui модуль упомянуть](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#examples) .

Comment: Напишите ответ я с удовольствием его отмечу ))
я этот модуль впервые слышу - он для всех операционок?

Comment: это просто вариант вам и другим читателям с похожей проблемой попробовать. А так я ваш вопрос не понимаю: вы говорите, что pywin32 (через COM управлять) вам не подходит, так "не подходит для openoffice", при этом вы используете вариант, который ещё сильнее зависит от конкретной программы (её GUI). Можно пофантазировать (прочитать ваши мысли) и предположить, что вас интересуют  команды, для которых существуют общепринятые сочетания клавиш в выбранных программах (но процесс чтения мыслей не надёжен)

Comment: Да мне сначала надо "хоть как-то". Поэтому -  любое решение хорошо.
А вообще - хочется передавать нажатия клавиш в подпроцесс.
Чтобы написать более универсальное нечто.
А задача такая. Kinect распознает жесты и листаем презентацию. Если у чела не окажется лицензионной винды - то что делать?
Как то управлять OpenOfice придется...

Comment: @VasylKolomiets так и скажите, что хотите сделать универсальный контроллер для любой программы презентации. На вашем бы месте писал для каждого конкретного случая свое, а если что нашел бы, уже объединил бы.

Comment: для более универсального советую спец. средства типа AutoIt. В контексте PowerPoint как и остальных продуктов офиса, ими можно управлять через апи в виде Com объектов : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/application-object-powerpoint

Comment: AutoIt - не нашел такого модуля  (( @Reishin

Comment: @VasylKolomiets ох, это не модуль. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/  это спец штука по автоматизации вещей и управлению приложениями