# pywinauto-пример из документации модуля не отрабатывает. Поможете?

Tags: python, pywinauto

[pywinauto-пример](http://pywinauto.github.io/) из документации запускает блокнот, открывает меню и - затыкается... Если кому интересно, то без строки закрытия окна `app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()`  текст в блокнот нормально выводится следующим оператором...
А то модуль то классный, но если у меня не работает даже их пример использования их модуля, то что то я не понимаю значит... Вот и прошу о помощи)
Кстати - на английской раскладке все работает...

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pywinauto.application import Application
# Run a target application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
# Select a menu item
#app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Довідка->Про програму")
# Click on a button
app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
# Type a text string
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

[image: Блокнот честно запускается и меню открывается....]

Ниже привожу начало и конец сообщений из которых следует, что пункта меню "ОК" в словаре не найдено.
Как видно в тексте программы - я изменил стандартную англоязычную строку примера - на украинский вариант. Так вот аналогичное сообщение выдавалось с рассказом что "не могут найти Help в словаре" и далее в словаре были указаны украинские названия - "&Довідка"... Надеюсь смог объяснить, что-то ))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 245, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 447, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/PyCodes/WOW/pptx/pywinauto _notepad-example.py", line 9, in <module> app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()   
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 351, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 248, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 425, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 209, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 84, in find_element
    elements = find_elements(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 300, in find_elements
    elements = findbestmatch.find_best_control_matches(best_match, wrapped_elems)
  File "C:\Users\Vasil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 533, in find_best_control_matches
    raise MatchError(items = name_control_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError:   
 Could not find 'OK' in 'dict_keys(['', 'Edit'])'
>>>
```

Comment: У меня на Windows 7 (English) - отрабатывает без ошибки, но "About" окошко не закрывается...

Comment: Похоже дело в кириллизации! в примере https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#attribute-resolution-magic                    вместо  app.Replace.print_control_identifiers()            надо набирать
app.Замінити.print_control_identifiers()
а ниже срабатывает:
app.Замінити.Скасувати.click()
!!!!!

Comment: А у меня получилось закрыть "About" окно - надо выполнить "app.AboutNotepad.OK.Click()" два раза - первый раз для того чтобы фокус попал на это окошко

Comment: Опубликуйте свое решение в виде ответа - это явно приветствуется правилами форума

Comment: вот еще интересный пример: https://gist.github.com/ProProgrammer/c02aed13b699d85f40e9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в кириллизации! Вот работающий в украинской раскладке код. Под русскую подправите сами, глядя на названия меню в "Блокноте".

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pywinauto.application import Application
# Run a target application
app = Application().start("notepad.exe")
# Select a menu item
#app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Help->About Notepad")
app.UntitledNotepad.menu_select("Довідка->Про програму")
# Click on a button
#app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()
app.Пропрограмублокнот.ОК.click()
# Type a text string
app.UntitledNotepad.Edit.type_keys("pywinauto Works!", with_spaces = True)
```

Да, вместо `app.AboutNotepad.OK.click()`  надо написать

```
app.Пропрограмублокнот.ОК.click()
```

Причем **ОК** - тоже надо набрать **кириллицей**. И - все работает.
Мое мнение - ребята перестарались с дружественностью кодирования. Если мне надо писать для разных раскладок мне нужно три кода (три модуля).  А используя модуль `win32com` мне нужно выбирать литералы в словаре. Так что я свой выбор остановил на "не дружественном" но практичном `win32com`.

Comment: не обязательно `obj.attr` синтаксис использовать. К примеру, вместо `app.UntitledNotepad`, [можно `app.window(best_match=_('UntitledNotepad'))` вызвать](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Один и тот же [код может несколько языков поддерживать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/735467/23044).

Comment: @jfs - я это и имел ввиду, когда говорил "сменять литералы в словаре". Точнее сказать ВЫБИРАТЬ. сча подправлю )

Comment: стоит упомянуть что если pywin32 работает для вас, то использование API конечно более предпочтительно, нежели по строкам в GUI нужную функциональность пытаться найти.

Comment: Пардон, только сейчас увидел вопрос. Разумеется, через GUI с локализацией всё сложно. Хотя pywinauto может запоминать историю действий на одном языке и потом воспроизводить на другом. Но этим, кажется, никто сейчас не пользуется, т.к. функциональность древняя (была ещё до того, как мы начали поддерживать библиотеку) и с тех пор практически не ревьюилась: то есть должна работать только в теории и в базовых юнит тестах.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov  -  да нет же - работает на десятой винде с ноутпадом... Код рабочий ))))  Кстати  -  с экзотической для Майкрософт украинской локализацией...   Говорю "экзотической" потому что функции например в экселе  не СУМ() или ВПР() а чисто по-украински:   SUM(), VLOOKUP()  :-) 
Хорошо, а как по-другому?

Comment: Для того же PowerPoint есть COM interface (как и для других продуктов MS Office), который можно юзать через `win32com.client` (пример для Excel есть в документации pyWin32 (встроенной в питон после установки `pip install pypiwin32`, имя пакета в pip чуть-чуть другое, исторически сложилось). COM объекты - это как раз и есть тот самый API, про который говорил jfs. Он не зависит от локализации, один скрипт, English only, должен работать для любого языка.

Comment: Проблема в том, что далеко не у всех GUI приложений реализованы COM объекты. Тот же Open Office - вообще на Qt4 собран. Его даже через GUI не очень удобно автоматизировать. Перешли бы на Qt5, было бы проще.

Comment: COM объекты можно юзать вообще из любого языка программирования, на самом деле. Хоть на VBScript, хоть на C++. Но это чисто виндузовая технология. Поэтому для работы с Excel файлами есть несколько разных Python пакетов, которые просто тупо формат Excel'я читают и пишут прямо в файл, зато работают и на линуксах тоже. Не оскудела земля кудесниками по reverse инжинирингу. :)